# from text deleting specific characters using re.sub

Tags: python, regex

```
m ='. Kansas City has a population of 475378. Local time in Kansas City is CST.'
d = re.sub('..*?.', '', m)
print(d)
```

I am trying to delete the line between the two periods.It gives me the same output How can i correct it?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dots with a backslash, they mean any character.  You are also better off using a negative character class instead of .*? as it is doing what you are really asking, 'all/any non dots':

```
[^.]*
```

Here is an example of what you are asking for.

```
import re

m ='. Kansas City has a population of 475378. Local time in Kansas City is CST.'
d = re.sub('\.[^.]*\.', '', m)
print(d)
```

If you want to keep the periods you can simply do this:

```
d = re.sub('\.[^.]*\.', '..', m)
```

http://regex101.com/ is a really good site to play around with your regex to tweak it exactly how you'd like to have it work.  Good luck!